# Android Custom Oath Steps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I gave been following firebase docs but I cannot find a linear step up process android firebase custom oath.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Whats are the tools I need,

Steps to set up.

I want users to setup using phonenumber and password.

Comment: You'll need a server to authenticate the user and mint a token for them. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you use Firebase alone?are there things I need to use and learn outside Firebase...,